# MobileFramework setup element.click null pointer exception

Tags: java, selenium, maven, appium

Trying to setup a mobile framework, and when using an element to click it is returning nullpointer and I seem to be overlooking why. `mobileAction.click(androidSignIn);` is what is returning as null pointer

ActionsPage:

```
import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;



import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;


public class mobileActionsPage extends MobileBaseClass{
    
    /**
     * constructor with driver as argument
     * 
     * @param driver
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public mobileActionsPage(AppiumDriver driver) {

        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); // initialize the objects
    }
    
    public void click(WebElement element) {
        element.click();
    }






}
```

BaseClass:

```
package mobilePages;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;



public class MobileBaseClass {

    public static Logger logg = Logger.getLogger(MobileBaseClass.class.getName());

    protected static AppiumDriver driver;


    /**
     * This function will execute before each Test tag in testng.xml
     * 
     * @param browser
     * @throws MalformedURLException
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters({ "mobileOS" })
    public void setup(String mobileOS) throws MalformedURLException {
        
        if(mobileOS.equalsIgnoreCase("android")) {
            
            //creating android instance
             DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();

                desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Pixel_4_API_31");
                desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
                desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","12");

                //THIS WILL CHANGE - Setup app center download on execution
                desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app","/usr/local/bin/connect_v5.0.10-249_2022-10-11_15.42.43 .apk");
                driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
        }
        
    }

        

    /**
     * This function will execute after each Test tag in testng.xml
     * 
     * @param none
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @AfterMethod
    public void teardown() {
        logg.info("****** Test Finished: Beginning teardown ******");
        logg.info("Closing browser");
        //driver.quit();
    }

}
```

LoginPage:

```
import java.time.Duration;

import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumBy;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import webPages.ActionsPage;
import webPages.AssertPage;
import webPages.BaseClass;


public class LoginPage extends MobileBaseClass{
    AppiumDriver driver;
    mobileActionsPage mobileAction = new mobileActionsPage(driver);
    /**
     * constructor with driver as argument
     * 
     * @param driver
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public LoginPage(AppiumDriver driver) {

        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this); // initialize the objects

    }
    
    //mobileActionsPage withAction = new mobileActionsPage(driver);
    
    //page objects
//  @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Sign In')]")
//  WebElement androidSignIn;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@text='Sign In']")
    WebElement androidSignIn;
    
    
//  String signInTitle = "//span[contains(text(),'Sign In')]";

    //methods
    /**
     * Navigates to access page from homepage
     */
    public void login() throws InterruptedException {
        //withAssert.verifyStringExists(signInTitle, "Sign in button is displayed");
//      new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(1000));
//      logg.info("Waited for 10 seconds");
//      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sign In')]"));
//      logg.info("Foudn locator");
//
//              element.click();
//              logg.info("clicking");



        Thread.sleep(5000);
        mobileAction.click(androidSignIn);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[1]")).sendKeys("String.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[2]")).sendKeys("String2xxx");
        mobileAction.click(androidSignIn);
    }
    

}
```

Test:

```
import mobilePages.LoginPage;
import mobilePages.MobileBaseClass;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

public class FirstAppiumTest extends MobileBaseClass {

    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        // locate the Text on the calculator by using By.name()
        logg.info("Waiting for app to load");
        loginPage.login();

    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="TestSuite">


    <test name="mobileTests">

        <parameter name="mobileOS" value="android" />

        <classes>

            <class name="mobileTests.FirstAppiumTest">

                <methods>
                    <include name="test1" />
                </methods>
            </class>


        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <testng.files.location>src/TestSuites/</testng.files.location>
        <testng.file>testng.xml</testng.file>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <gridUrl></gridUrl>
    </properties>
    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${SuiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

If I run the test using the following it works fine:

`public void click(String xpath) {        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click(); }`

However the same test using this fails using element.click();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LoginPage, initialize mobileAction in the constructor after initializing the driver. You are initializing the mobileAction with the null driver.